# Any alternative for dbmail for Ubuntu 18.04 Package

Tags: email, mail

I tried to install `dbmail` package in my Ubuntu 18.04, But it looks like, the package was long ago removed from the repository.

Is there any other alternative package for `dbmail` for Ubuntu 18.04?

The package that stores the mail-in database and not in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything named `dbmail` in [standard repositories from 16.04 LTS to 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=dbmail).
But I can find this package only for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (EOL):

> ```
> # apt-cache policy dbmail
> dbmail:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 2.2.11-1build1
>   Version table:
>      2.2.11-1build1 0
>         500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe amd64 Packages
>      2.2.9-1ubuntu1 0
>         500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy/universe amd64 Packages
> ```

There is no such package for [deb-based distros on Repology](https://repology.org/project/dbmail/versions).
But for example [ArchLinux has v3.2.3 from 2019-08-06](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/dbmail/), so the project is alive.

So we can download, compile and create deb-package of it from [official site](http://www.dbmail.org/) manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.dbmail.org/download/3.2/dbmail-3.2.3.tar.gz
tar -xf dbmail-3.2.3.tar.gz
cd dbmail-3.2.3/

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts \
automake libsieve2-dev libgmime-2.6-dev libldap2-dev libzdb-dev \
libmhash-dev libevent-dev asciidoc xmlto libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev
# also you need to choose from MySQLDB or MariaDB:
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev # or libmariadbclient-dev 

rm debian/source/format # disable 3.0 (quilt) format
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -d # "-d" to ignore 'missed' automake1.9
# wait it to get compiled

# install the package
sudo apt-get install ../dbmail_*.deb
```

Then check it

> ```
> $ dbmail-util -V | head -n1
> This is dbmail 3.2.3
> ```

---

Note: I have never used this software, just compiled it to help you.